# What is the best way of notifying RecylerView about dataset changes when these changes happen in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I've looked up the documentation of `RecyclerView.Adapter` to find out how different `notify...` methods work. It states

> If you are writing an adapter it will always be more efficient to use the more specific change events if you can. Rely on notifyDataSetChanged() as a last resort.

Clicking an item of my `RecyclerView` starts an activity containing a `ViewPager`. The `ViewPager` uses `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. As a result I am able to swipe views and make changes in them if I wish to do so. When my pager hosting activity is finished, I have to notify the adapter of the `RecyclerView` about the changes. I can only see 2 possible ways to proceed:

1. I can set up a communication channel like this: fragments of the pager notify the hosting activity if they are edited -> the hosting activity sends a list of all the changes to the parent activity when it finishes -> the parent activity calls `notifyItemChanged()` on the `RecylerView.Adapter` for all the changes. I cannot think of a way of implementing this that is not ugly.
2. I say that this is the last resort and bluntly call 'notifyDataSetChanged()` and the problem is gone but there is no proof that it won't slow down the app.

I'm quite new to this so maybe I'm missing an obvious solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both approaches can be applied depending on the situation. To make a correct decision you should consider potential amount of items which will be changed and a total amount of items in your list.

Not so many total items or many changes - use `notifyDataSetChanged`.

A lot of list items or single change - use 1st approach.

Approach #1 can be easily implemented by calling `startActivityForResult` and expect back in `onActivityResult` a list of changed items' ids.

Don't forget - you can always measure and compare performances for both approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `startActivityForResult()` seems logical for one part of the communication channel. What would you use for the second part? Fragment pages need a way to send data to their hosting activity.

Comment: @LimboExile here is the way how to pass data from Fragment to Activity
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Got it. It bothered me a little that the fragment now knows about a method of its activity, but since the official site recommends this too, then it should be the way to go.

Comment: Yes, it feels weird but interface makes them decoupled. Kinda :)